# When Live Activity updates data, the picture will fade in and fade out, how to turn off this animation effect?

Tags: swiftui, dynamic-island, activitykit

> Animate content updates
>
> When you define the user interface of your Live Activity, the system ignores any animation modifiers — for example, [withAnimation(_:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/withAnimation(_:_:)?changes=_2_2) and [animation(_:value:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/animation(_:value:)?changes=_2_2) — and uses the system’s animation timing instead. However, the system performs some animation when the dynamic content of the Live Activity changes. Text views animate content changes with blurred content transitions, and the system animates content transitions for images and SF Symbols. If you add or remove views from the user interface based on content or state changes, views fade in and out. Use the following view transitions to configure these built-in transitions: [opacity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyTransition/opacity?changes=_2_2), [move(edge:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyTransition/move(edge:)?changes=_2_2), [slide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyTransition/slide?changes=_2_2), [push(from:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyTransition/push(from:)?changes=_2_2), or combinations of them. Additionally, request animations for timer text with [numericText(countsDown:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/ContentTransition/numericText(countsDown:)?changes=_2_2).

When Live Activity updates data, the picture will fade in and fade out, how to turn off this animation effect?

I tried all possible ways to turn off the animation, but when refreshing the Live Activity, the picture still has a semi-transparent animation.

Comment: I am having this same exact issue. Based off of Uber/Lyft Live Activities it should be possible to prevent this fade out/in animation on images. In my case this is occurring on my logo (IconImage) and a UIImage from a iOS app group. Need a solution to this.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tricky issue, in the sense that my experience is that different View types require different solutions.

- I have a `ProgressView` on my Live Activity `DynamicIsland` view, for which I had to use the `.transition(.identity)` modifier to stop the progress bar from the flashing animation. **Note:** `.contentTransition(.identity)` did not work for this view.
- I also have several `Image` views on my Live Activity's `DynamicIsland` view, for which I had to use a different solution.

This is my Image code simplified:

```
let url: URL? = <some URL>

if let url, 
   let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url) 
{
    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        .contentTransition(.identity)
}
```

I have tried several other methods to stop the `Image` from flashing, with different results:

- `.transition(.identity)`: no effect.
- wrapping the Image in a View struct that also conforms to `Equatable` and marking this wrapper view with the `.equatable()` modifier: the flashing got greatly reduced, but still happened sporadically.
- `.contentTransition(.identity)`: worked, the `Image` completely stopped flashing.

Comment: ```.contentTransition(.identity): worked, the Image completely stopped flashing.``` works great, should be accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Based on apple's [developer documentation for ActivityKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities#Animate-content-updates), **You cannot change the default animation for Live Activities. The system ignores any animation modifiers that you specify and uses its own animation timing instead. However, you can configure the built-in transitions for adding and removing views, and for timer text.**

To achieve no effect, you can use multiple views that pop in and out based on the content state.

```swift
if !context.state.imageName.isEmpty {
  Image(systemName: context.state.imageName)
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    .padding(.trailing, 10)
} else {
  Image("live-activity-logo")
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    .padding(.trailing, 10)
}
```

You can use the `transition` modifier for these views to appear in an animated way as described in the documentation.

Comment: Apple's developer documentation states "If you add or remove views from the user interface based on content or state changes, views fade in and out". I'm not sure about the code that Wen Su is using, but in my code I am definitely not removing and adding my images. These transitions should not be happening and your answer is misleading.